# Is there a way to stretch a stage so that it fills the whole screen in javafx?

Tags: javafx, resize, javafx-2, stage, stretch

I was wondering if there was a way to stretch the stage in javafx because I want my application to fit any screen. So, ss there a way to stretch a stage so that it fills the whole screen in javafx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [setFullScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen-boolean-) method of the Stage class.

Comment: Is there a way to stretch the contents as-well similar to this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_aPYk_FJV5HUThoMUpJRTVqdDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you mean? Full size with title bar? In that case do what tomsontom says and use the maximized property.

Comment: Re-size all of the nodes in the scene so that they are proportional to the stage. Is that possible?

Comment: Put the nodes on a Pane and use the setScale method of the Pane.

Answer (score 1):

Set the fullscreen or maximized property of the Stage to true

Comment: Is there a way to stretch the contents as-well similar to this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_aPYk_FJV5HUThoMUpJRTVqdDA/view?usp=sharing